# How to change user_login with wp-cli?

Tags: users, wp-cli

How to change the username with [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org)?

This does not work:

```
wp user update old_login --user-login=new_login
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Not allowed by design:

If we try to change the user login by the email:

```
wp user update mary@example.tld --user_login=mary_new
```

or by the user id:

```
wp user update 123 --user_login=mary_new
```

we get the following warning:

> User logins can't be changed.

This is the reason:

```
if ( isset( $assoc_args['user_login'] ) ) {
    WP_CLI::warning( "User logins can't be changed." );
    unset( $assoc_args['user_login'] );
}
```

within the `user` `update` [method](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/becebdc58cbc2e5caabee6ebfc111d0de44f423e/php/commands/user.php#L340-L343).

### Possible workarounds:

**Custom SQL queries:**

If we only want to target the `wp_users` table and the `user_login` field, it's possible to run the SQL query with:

```
wp db query "UPDATE wp_users SET user_login = 'mary_new' WHERE user_login = 'mary'"
```

But we have to make sure the user logins are **unique**.

I experiented with this kind of query:

```
wp db query "UPDATE wp_users u, 
    ( SELECT 
          COUNT(*) as number_of_same_login_users
          FROM wp_users u 
          WHERE user_login = 'mary_new' 
    ) tmp 
    SET u.user_login = 'mary_new' 
    WHERE 
            u.user_login = 'mary_old' 
        AND tmp.number_of_same_login_users = 0"
```

to enforce the uniqueness of the `user_login` field, by only updating, if the no user has the same user login name.

[This unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18153569/2078474) helped me constructing an UPDATE with a subquery.

Here's the same command in a single line:

```
wp db query "UPDATE wp_users u, ( SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_same_login_users FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = 'mary_new' ) tmp SET u.user_login = 'mary_new' WHERE u.user_login = 'mary_old' AND tmp.number_of_same_login_users = 0"
```

but this is kind of query should be inside a custom command ;-)

Note that the table prefix might be different than `wp_`.

**Custom WP-CLI commands:**

Like explained in the [Commands Cookbook](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Commands-Cookbook), it's possible to create custom WP-CLI commands.

We might try to build a custom command like:

```
    WP_CLI::add_command( 'wpse_replace_user_login', 'WPSE_Replace_User_Login' );
```

or:

```
    WP_CLI::add_command( 'wpse_user', 'WPSE_User_Command' );
```

where `WPSE_User_Command` extends the `User_Command` class. This would need further work.

Comment: Ah, it's enough to only change `wp_users.user_login`?

Comment: I updated the answer how we could update the user login without duplications. Maybe you got a better idea for that part. By using a custom command, we could just use two SQL queries, instead of a single one. The user login is defined in the wp_users table on single site install. The table prefix might be different. @KasperSouren

Answer (score 6):

`search-replace` does the trick but can have undesired side effects if `old_login` appears in other contexts in the database:

```
wp search-replace old_login new_login
```

But before doing that run

```
wp sql dump
wp search-replace old_login new_login --dry-run
```

To make an SQL dump and see what is going to be replaced.

Comment: You better take backup first ;-) and maybe use `--dry-run` to check the extend of the replacements.

Comment: Right. I actually did this before running it myself. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: While potentially dangerous, this is great for some uses. I didn't even think of it, so thanks!